# Interdependencies in self created angular libraries

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have created two customized library say, table lib and input lib. Table lib has dependency on input library. We can specify the relative path to input lib in table lib, this would work for build of table lib. However, when we use the table lib in app, which is of course in other directory,  table lib cant resolve the dependecy over input lib. What is the standard way of solving it without using extern library such as nx? Thanks.

i have tried to add absolute path to input lib in table lib. Table lib can resolve its dependency on input lib in app locally. But this method is awkward, because the build.gradle must run first when ever we use the library locally. It cant apply to user when we pack the project.

Comment: try path alias in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: tsconfig.json uses relative or absolute path. when we use the Table lib in a complete different host, either would work

Comment: then you need to publish it as a package in a registry like npm or private

Comment: Thanks for you advise. I suggested this to my supervisor but he rejected this idea. He thinks there must be a better and standard method. I will do more research and convince him.

Comment: classic response from managers when they do not understand the problem. Good luck

Comment: acctually he is a senior programmer and always want perfection. But i think we have to use the publish method to solve the dependencies.